# I cant find this memory leak. I thought I was releasing everything properly

Tags: objective-c, debugging, ios, memory-leaks

I cannot find this memory leak. I thought I had been releasing things properly. Here is the block of code in question.

```
 - (void) createProvince:(NSString *) provinceName {

    // if province does not exist create it
    if ([self hasProvince: provinceName] == NO) {

        // get the province object
        NSPredicate *predicate;
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name == %@", provinceName];

        NSMutableArray *provArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [provArray setArray: [CoreDataHelper searchObjectsInContext:@"Province" :predicate :@"Name" :YES :[self managedObjectContext]]];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath;
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection: 0];

        [[self provinces] addObject: [provArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];
        [provArray release];

        // create a cities array to hold its selected cities
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [[self cities] addObject: array];
        [array release];
    }
}
```

The leaks are here:

```
[[self provinces] addObject: [provArray objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[[self cities] addObject: array];
```

I am creating the local variables, assigning them to my instance variables through the proper setters, and then releasing the local variables. I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `dealloc` method that is properly releasing everything?

Note that leaks is showing you where something was allocated.  It doesn't show you where it was actually leaked;  what retain wasn't explicitly balanced.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[[self cities] addObject: array];
[array release];
```

When you `alloc` an object, its retain count is set to 1:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; # retain count of array is 1
```

When you add an object to an `NSMutableArray`, that object's `retain` count is incremented:

```
[[self cities] addObject: array]; # retain count of array is 2
```

When you `release` the `array`, its retain count is decremented:

```
[array release]; # retain count is now 1
```

Once your method ends, you still have that array owned by the mutable array `[self cities]`.

Because `[self cities]` doesn't appear to get released or emptied, this is where you get a leak.

You need to empty or release the mutable array at some point, releasing the objects contained within. If `cities` is a class property, perhaps `release` it when the class is released.

**EDIT**

Fixed `init`-`alloc` mistake.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I have a dealloc that should be getting called to release cities, but its not. This, i think, tells me that there are unreleased objects that need to be released first.

Comment: `init` does not change the retain count of an object;  `alloc` allocates with a retain count of +1.  Absolute retain counts are useless.